# on the existence of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, semidirect-product

Let $G$ be a non-nilpotent group such that $p,q \in \pi(G)$, the set of all prime divisor of $|G|$.
If $p \mid q-1$, then can we say that there is subgroup $S$ which has the form
$S=P_1 \ltimes Q_1$, where $|Q_1|=q$ and $|P_1|=p^t$?

Comment: What is $\pi(G)$?

Comment: Is $\pi(G)$ the set of prime divisors of $|G|$? Do you want $P_1$ to be a $p$-group? Why not take the trivial group for $P_1$?

Comment: Does $\text{SL}(2,64)$ have a subgroup of order $39$? I don't think so.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos @ Hagen von Eitzen Yes

Answer (score 1):

As ancientmathematician pointed out, this isn't true in general.  However, there is a smaller, easier to comprehend counterexample.

Consider the group of order 72 given by $D_8\ltimes 3^2$ with $D_8$ acting by the usual matrices of 0s, 1s, and -1s that also represent it over the real plane.  There is no normal subgroup of order 3.  (For clarity, $3^2$ is the  standard group-theory notation for the elementary abelian group of order 9.)

Indeed, if your statement were true even for solvable groups, then all irreducible representations of all $p$-groups over $\Bbb{F}_q$ would be one-dimensional, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: My example has the advantage of *being* simple. Hmm.

Comment: This is the first good pun I've seen on this site.  Thanks!

Comment: @C Monsour why $H$ has a unique $q$-Sylow?

Comment: Oops, it doesn't.  The counterexample is still good though..

Comment: that is $Q$ is not normal in $PQ$?

Comment: To clarify for future readers, that refers to a two prime example that has since been deleted from the answer.  It may not be the case that $PQ$ has any normal Sylow subgroups.  For example $GL_2{\Bbb{F}_3}\ltimes 3^2$ (in the natural action), of order 432, is solvable but has no normal Sylow subgroups.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $G=\text{SL}(2,64)$, $p=3$, $q=13=1+4\cdot3$.

The normaliser of the Sylow-$13$-subgroup is $D_{2\cdot65}$.